# Want to match two date columns of two tables both have diff formats in mysql

Tags: mysql

One column format is like '2005-03-22' and other is like '2005-03-22  22:09:01'.. i tried to_date function but its not working in mysql..which function should i use?

Comment: Do you want to convert a *timestamp* to a *date*? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251561/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mysql-query

Answer (score 1):

Found it... it will be `date_format(date , '%Y- %m- %d')`

Comment: I don't see any spaces in your example data??

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT DATE('2005-03-22') = DATE('2005-03-22 22:09:01');
+--------------------------------------------------+
| DATE('2005-03-22') = DATE('2005-03-22 22:09:01') |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                1 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Looks like it works.  Please elaborate on what you did differently.